# Limit in R in terms of another variable

Tags: r

I need to take a limit of a function $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ in R but I want the answer in terms of n. I tried defining n as a symbol but it did not work. I am new to R so I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: R is probably the wrong tool for this job (taking limits, solving equations symbolically); you can link it to symbolic math tools (e.g. see the `Ryacas` package), but you're probably better off with a symbolic math toolbox/platform: e.g. Mathematica, Wolfram Alpha, Maple, Sagemath, sympy, …

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to take the limit of this function for x->1, you can obtain the result by using the package Ryacas in the following way:

```
require(Ryacas)
x <- Sym("x")
n <- Sym("n")
Limit((x^n-1)/(x-1),x,1)
```

which yields the answer:

```
expression(n)
```

Comment: Just a follow-up question, I used the same process to evaluate the limit $\frac{x^n(n + 1)}{x - 1} - \frac{x^(n + 1) - 1}{(x - 1)^2}$ but R returned the value as expression (0). Computing the limit on Wolfram returns $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.